# domain/controller/action/id how to write it

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

i have cakephp url like this
`domin.com/products/mobile/3`
i want to do it cakephp like this
For product id i want to show it like this : `domain.com/3` 
`domian.com/products/nokiamobiles` to `domain.com/nokiamobiles`

```
class productsController extends AppController{
    public function mobile($id){
        $this->set('nokia',$this->Product->findById($id));
        }
 public function nokiaMobiles(){

     $this->set('nokia',$this->Product->find('all'));

      }


}
```

Comment: I dont understand, you want all 3 routes to work?? Thats duplicated content

Comment: As your need, I think there is no other way but to write a Custom Route Class...

Answer (score 0):

Route For first one:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:id',
    'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'mobile',
    array('id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

For second:

```
Router::connect(
    '/nokiamobiles',
    array('controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'nokiamobiles')
);
```

For more [CakePHP Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html)

Comment: fist one is showing error i think controller and action we define in array